# parseFloat whole number with two decimal points -Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

Below i have a use case, where a number is stored in db as decimal(18, 2). When trying to read the data, the numbers with .00 are converted to integer.

Using .toFixed(2) changes the format from number to string. // as expected.

How can i retain the format.

**Input**

```
    const x1 = 4000.00;
    const x2 = 4000.01;

    const y1 = parseFloat((x1).toFixed(2)); // actual: 4000 expected: 4000.00
    const y2 = parseFloat((x2).toFixed(2)); // actual: 4000.01 expected: 4000.01

    // const y1 = parseFloat((x1).toFixed(2)).toFixed(2); //datatype: actual: string, expected: number 
    // const y2 = parseFloat((x2).toFixed(2)).toFixed(2); //datatype: actual: string, expected: number

    console.log(typeof(y1), y1);
    console.log(typeof(y2), y2);
```

Comment: `4000.00` is precisely the same value as `4000`

Comment: Also it doesn't really make sense to call `parseFloat()` on the result of `.toFixed()`. If you're doing this for display, it doesn't matter if the values are strings.

Comment: Yep. As @Pointy, err... Pointed out, they're the same number. As `Float`s and `Integer`s are `Number` types, and JavaScript only has a `Number` type primitive, it doesn't see a difference between them both. Something like Java would have a difference, but JavaScript doesn't differentiate.

Comment: @Pointy I accept that 4000 == 4000.00. It  is an api call and the frontend is expecting the field as number datatype with two decimals. I cannot wrap it with quotes using toFixed

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene then the problem is with the API.

Comment: @Pointy I think I miscommunicated. I am designing the api and my api gives the output as 4000, but the requirement is 4000.00 as datatype number not as string.. Is it possible?

Comment: The internal representation of JavaScript number is *binary* floating point, not decimal. "4000.00" is a string rendition of a binary floating point value as a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

`decimal(18,2)` is a fixed-precision number format, here meaning "18 decimal digit, with 2 of them to the right of the decimal point". Typically stored as either packed decimal or an integer. with precision and scale maintained by the programming language.

Javascript numbers are not like that. They are IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating point numbers: they have a *floating* decimal (binary) point, and trade precision for range.

You need to read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, or *Why don’t my numbers add up?*](https://floating-point-gui.de/).